# Attaching file to activity

Tags: activities

I'm having a problem attaching files to activities.  I've done the basic checks (write permission to directories, Drupal permissions) .  I notice that the file gets placed in the Custom Files folder "[site root]\sites\default\files\civicrm\custom"

However, the process doesn't seem to finish, and the system hangs with the egg timer showing and ultimately i have to escape out of adding the activity, for the system to 'un-freeze'.

I'm feel it's just a small tweak somewhere but i'm getting stupped what the exact issue is, and my searches are not pulling up anything related to this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: when i right click new activity and attach the file i get the following error

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Could not
>   move custom file to custom upload directory Uncaught
>   CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find
>   active frame thrown in –

UPDATE 2:
 it looks like there is a 500 error;

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error).

this is followed by another errror;

> Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are
>   unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are
>   being made on file resources. SecurityError –

UPDATE #3
It looks like the ultimate cause of this problem is the issue with relative angular paths in windows [CRM-16499](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5863).  I'm going to upgrade to 4.6.4 from 4.6.2 as this issues is fixed in the 4.6.4 version.

If it works i'll add an answer

Comment: Can you verify that your file permisions are correct (usually this means www-data user ought to have rw permission on the sites/default/files/* directory)

Comment: Bruce it looks like there are two of you! Which one is the real Bruce?

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved as of 4.6.4 ([issue CRM-16499](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16499)).